# Markdown inserts paragraphs for consecutive lists

Tags: markdown

This source

```
  1.  Lorem ipsum dolor voluptate amet id minim eiusmod. 
    1.  Lorem ipsum do occaecat anim do tempor ad. 

  1.  Lorem ipsum Ut sed anim voluptate id aliquip. Lorem ipsum esse ut voluptate non Ut ullamco sunt laborum occaecat non et consequat est ut qui esse. 
  2.  Lorem ipsum aliquip amet consectetur in pariatur labore exercitation proident veniam nisi qui veniam. 
  3.  Lorem ipsum cupidatat ad dolor id veniam in mollit nisi deserunt.
```

Outputs...

```
<ol>
<li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor voluptate amet id minim eiusmod. </p>

<ol><li>Lorem ipsum do occaecat anim do tempor ad. </li></ol></li>
<li><p>Lorem ipsum Ut sed anim voluptate id aliquip. Lorem ipsum esse ut voluptate non Ut ullamco sunt laborum occaecat non et consequat est ut qui esse. </p></li>
<li>Lorem ipsum aliquip amet consectetur in pariatur labore exercitation proident veniam nisi qui veniam. </li>
<li>Lorem ipsum cupidatat ad dolor id veniam in mollit nisi deserunt. </li>
</ol>
```

This is a simplification. I actually want something more like this...

```
1.  Lorem ipsum dolor voluptate amet id minim eiusmod.

  Lorem ipsum officia ea ex Excepteur minim sint id occaecat Duis voluptate Duis. Lorem ipsum do dolor Ut est qui aliquip quis in amet. 

  1.  Lorem ipsum do occaecat anim do tempor ad. 

2.  Lorem ipsum magna mollit labore aliqua fugiat dolore fugiat esse et culpa cupidatat magna ut labore. 

  Lorem ipsum irure incididunt elit officia magna nulla. 

  1.  Lorem ipsum Ut sed anim voluptate id aliquip. Lorem ipsum esse ut voluptate non Ut ullamco sunt laborum occaecat non et consequat est ut qui esse. 
  2.  Lorem ipsum aliquip amet consectetur in pariatur labore exercitation proident veniam nisi qui veniam. 
  3.  Lorem ipsum cupidatat ad dolor id veniam in mollit nisi deserunt.
```

How is it deciding whether to put a paragraph or not?
How can I work around the issue

Comment: What code are you using to parse the MD?

Comment: I used several - including the one on daring fireball's site. They all produce the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tip: use an HTML comment between consecutive lists:

```
* element 1
* element 2
* element 3

<!-- -->

* element 1
* element 2
```

See http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html (Ending a list)

Answer (score 0):

Try [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc).  It won't put in the `<p>` tags for your input.  Here's an explanation of [the rule pandoc uses](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#compact-and-loose-lists) and a discussion of Markdown.pl's output in the very kind of case you give.